# Android: Within Android Device Chooser the same device shows up several times

Tags: device, android

I am using Eclipse to program for the Android OS. I use a real device to test my application on.

To test my application I click on run, then the target project i wanna run and then the Android Device Chooser pops up, where I can choose the device or emulator that I want to run the application. (like probably every programmer here).

But sometimes when my app crashes because of some exception, the Android Device Handler gets some weired behavior. Now everytime I connect my device to the computer via USB a new device shows up in the Android Device Chooser, but all them (which are the same) are "unknown", so I cant use my device for testing anymore.

[image]
<sub>(source: [yfrog.com](http://a.yfrog.com/img51/1387/androiddeviceshooser.png))</sub>

The only way to solve this is by restarting my computer. Isnt there any other way to solve the problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: Check the solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429959/android-device-chooser-not-showing-android-device/4079361

I found mine there!

Answer (score 2):

In your command line. (assuming ADB is on your path)

Try:

```
adb kill-server

adb start-server

adb devices
```

Comment: Yep, this worked. Unplugging device, restarting it and restarting eclipse haven't change a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Unplug the device from the system.
Restart the eclipse IDE.
Goto the device development setting, uncheck and then check the USB debugging.
Issue will be resolved.

Comment: Not necessary to restart Eclipse.