# Captivate's ID coming up as "?????????" in manual emulator selector in Android Eclipse Manager

Tags: android-emulator

Solution: [Why is Eclipse's Android Device Chooser not showing my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429959/android-device-chooser-not-showing-android-device/4079361#4079361)

> THis is getting annoying.  My device shows up in eclipse on all
>   platforms.. Except when I am on my Ubuntu laptop.. when I "run
>   configurations" with it set to Manual.. I can see that there is an
>   Emmulator running that I can Install the App to.
>
> Problem is, the Emulator is a pile of horse crap when it comes to
>   testing on real devices like my Samsung Captivate.
>
> When the Captivate is plugged in via USB.. it shows via ICON, except
>   the ID is set to ??????????? and nothing else seems to be registering.
>   I can highlight it, but I can't launch it.
>
> The captivate I am using is Rooted and running the LagFix Kernal..
>   However this has never hindered me on Windows or OSX.
>
> Help.. I am trying to go completely Linux.. if it kills me.
>
> See screenshot below: http://img265.imageshack.us/i/sdkbugeclipse.png/
>
> UPDATE:  Device is showing in the manager even when not connected?!?! 
>   This has to be some weird Eclipse bug.. PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Solution (in case you missed my edit) need to add the correct Samsung Device ID when using the SDK with Ubuntu:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429959/android-device-chooser-not-showing-android-device/4079361#4079361)

Comment: Also, with the captivate.. if the Samsung USB drivers don't work with XP, load the USB Driver from the Android SDK for ADB compat.