# Problem to run my application on a real device

Tags: android, ubuntu-10.04

I am developing android application under **Linux Ubuntu 10.04**, with **Eclipse** IDE.

I successfully managed to run my application through eclipse virtual device emulator (target **android2.1-update1**).

Then, I followed the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) to run my application on a [ZTE tablet](http://www.techchee.com/2010/10/13/zte-unveils-7-inch-lightweight-android-tablet/) device through eclipse. I followed every step of the tutorial.

My rules file is located under  */etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules*, with content:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="19D2", MODE="0666"
```

The vendor ID of ZTE is 19D2.

I also enabled USB debugging both on the ZTE device and in my application's manifest file.

When I run the application in Eclipse, there is a "Android Device chooser" window popped up, which shows a device with:

**serial number:** "?????????????"

**AVD name:** N/A

**target :** Unknown

**Debug:**

Why eclipse can not recognize the ZTE tablet device correctly?? 
What could be the possible reason?

(I also tried to reboot my linux machine, but nothing changed)

**State:** ??

Comment: See the link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429959/android-device-chooser-not-showing-android-device]

Comment: @Leem does this link help? [http://mist.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/blog/?p=331](http://mist.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/blog/?p=331)

Answer (score 3):

Change the line to `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="19D2", MODE="0666"`

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` to:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="19D2", OWNER="user", GROUP="group"
```

where `user` is the username of the account you develop under; and `group` is the group of the account you developer under.

Comment: Do I need to restart my ubuntu machine after the change?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt. You'll definitely need to restart adb, and restarting the machine will certainly do this.

Comment: After change, I run: adb kill-server,
adb start-server,
adb devices, But I got the listed device"????????????? no permissions"

Comment: First try to run `adb start-server` as root. If that works look at your user & group in your rules file, they must match those of the account that `adb start-server` is run from.

Comment: @ Mark , when I run adb start-server as root with command "sudo adb start-server" I got "sudo: adb: command not found" , why?

Comment: Most likely because adb is not in the command search path for your root account. You may need to provide the full path to adb when running it as root.

Comment: @Leem let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1171/discussion-between-mark-allison-and-leem)

Answer (score 1):

??? symbols means that device is either offline or adb has not wright permission to access the device.Inorder to change the permission we need to update /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules file in the following way.

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1782" ,MODE="0666"

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0666"

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0666"

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666"

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666"

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666"

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0489", MODE="0666"

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", SYMLINK+="android_adb", MODE="0666"

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

using lsusb command to find vender id..