# Running android app on my lenovoA328 phone

Tags: android

I have installed adb usb drivers for lenovoA328 and updated from `Mycomputer->manage->other devices->update`.
When I am running my app then the Android Device Chooser shows:

```
Serial number -PF6LT8LVQ8BMS87T
AVD Name - n/a
Target - unknown
State - ?
```

Comment: Have you tried researching? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580133/problem-to-run-my-application-on-a-real-device

Answer (score 0):

Did you enabled Usb debugging on and under developer option . 
i think you have forgotten this, if this is the case please enable usb debugging in the developer option.