# Android 'Debug enabled device' is not showing up on Eclipse

Tags: android

I have gone through a lot of threads before posting this here. I am facing an issue with Android device debugging - the device isn't getting listed on Devices tab in Eclipse IDE. (To get 'Devices' tab 'Windows -> Show view -> Devices'). So while starting to debug there is no way to choose a device as device listing shows blank. The strange thing is that it used to work fine before and under windows explorer I can browse the files.

I am using Windows Vista Home premium, 32-bit OS

What all I have tried:

In phone:

- USB debugging is enabled in phone under 'Settings-> Developer
  options'
- Disabled and enabled USB debugging
- Restarted the phone

In Eclipse:

- Under 'Debug configurations->Target(tab)', 'Always prompt to pick
  device' is selected. It prompts but doesn't show any device on the
  device list!
- Tried resting ADB under Devices tab. (To get 'Devices' tab 'Windows
  -> Show view -> Devices'
- Reinstalled latest Android SDK along with ADB
- Installed Eclipse Juno

In windows CMD under /platform-tools/ directory where the Android SDK Tools is installed, ran the following commands without getting any positive outcome:
Shut down Eclipse, unplugged the device and tried running:
    adb kill-server
    adb start-server

Plugged it back in and ran
    adb devices

Mobile device details:

- Model = Galaxy S2 GT-i9100
- Rooted = yes
- OS Ver. = 4.0.3
- Kernel ver. = 3.0.15
- hardcore@speedmod-s2-ics #k3-27b

  Eclipse version: Indigo Service Release 1
  Build id: 20110916-0149

Edit1: I am ending up getting this error message on Eclipse console:
"[2012-10-09 12:39:22 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2012-10-09 12:39:23 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1"
I believe the problem is with the ADB driver. I have installed the latest SDK so the driver is also latest. Is there any other way to install the ADB driver?

Comment: I Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429959/why-is-eclipses-android-device-chooser-not-showing-my-android-device/31587496#31587496) will help everyone who is facing same issue.

Answer (score 7):

Is your phone set to charge only? I know my phone will not connect in Eclipse if it is set to storage mode. If you can view it in the Windows Explorer, that may be the cause of your problem.

Other than that, sometimes when I run into this sort of problem I do the following:

```
1. Unplug phone from PC
2. Disable USB Debugging in phone
3. Plug phone into PC
4. Unplug phone from PC
5. Enable USB Debugging in phone
6. Plug phone into PC
```

If my phone is being difficult and not showing up in Eclipse, or if it is showing up but not allowing me to select it for debugging, doing this once or twice usually fixes it.

Comment: In ICS 4.0.3, either you can have device debugging or set storage mode  enabled, both things cannot be enabled at the same time. In my case the former is enabled.
Tried your tips but still need some luck.

I am ending up getting this error message on Eclipse console: "[2012-10-09 12:39:22 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host [2012-10-09 12:39:23 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1" I believe the problem is with the ADB driver. I have installed the latest SDK so the driver is also latest. Last resort is to change the kernel!

Answer (score 0):

Might seem obvious, but have you tried to uninstall all drivers, reinstall most current ones (and correct ones), and try to restart your computer? I've tested on multiple phones at work, and a lot of weird issues like this was resolved, at least for me, through reinstalling drivers! Seems like you went through a lot of software issues, perhaps its time to try the hardware.

Comment: Yes. 
- Installed latest SDK(installer_r20.0.3-windows.exe) along with which the ADB driver also comes.
- Tried restarting the computer multiple times.

But what do you exactly mean by 'its time to try the hardware', are you referring to change the kernel or something?

Comment: The drivers that are associated with your Galaxy S2? Have you got them directory from Samsung's website?

Comment: The driver is as it is, have got whatever came with the phone.

Comment: I meant installing a driver on your computer that is meant for your galaxy s2

Comment: Just now tried that.
Uninstalled the drivers. Then they automatically got re-installed as the device was plugged in. But still no luck.

Comment: installed the latest driver from Samsung's site. It worked!
Thanks for your help. :-)

Comment: Link to the latest driver from Samsung, released on 25th Sep 2012
http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/GT-I9100LKAXEU-downloads

Answer (score 0):

Try **Reset adb** option in your **Devices** view

Comment: Done that from Eclipse as well as from CMD, task manager. As I have mentioned in my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem
Fixed by:
1. Uninstall old Kies mini
2. Install: SAMSUNG Kies,PC Sync (Software) (ver.2.3.3.12085_7_5) 
  from http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads/global#global_download_list

work as charm :)

Answer (score 0):

I too faced same issue long back, these are the possible solutions i have tried.In my case sol2 worked.

sol 1:

goto settings>Developer options > enable debugging.(try this by connecting yourdevice  on ad off)

sol2:

goto platform tools in your terminal. and try these commands
  1. ./adb kill-server
  2. ./adb start-server
  3. ./adb devices

sol3:

1. in your eclipse click on the device icon.(if the icon is not present then follow the steps windows>show view>others> device) 
   2.right side corner you will find down arrow mark click on that
2. clcik on restart adb.

sol4: 
  restart your eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the minimum android version that your project needs?

My current project needs an android version over 4.x, so any device under that isn't recognized. It might seem obvious, but just make sure that your device's version is up-to-date enough to be able to be used in your project :)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem before. I've tried everything that everybody mentioned, but didn't work.

However, I had this program called EasyTether. This actually blocked adb connection. After removing the program, it started working like a magic.

Do you have that any chance? or do you have any other software on PC that deals with direct connection between the device and PC? If you do,try removing it and try again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps to resolve the problem

1. Go To windows Task Manager
2. Stop Adb.exe
3. Restart Your Phone