# Eclipse doesn't recognize SGS3 device

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, adt

I'm running a small android project on eclipse ADT bundle.
When I debug it on my SGS1 phone it works fine.

However, when trying to debug it on a new SGS3 device,
the device is not shown on the targets devices and I can't debug it.

I've already enabled USB debugging on the device,
And installed Keis and the device driver (for windows 7, 64 bit), And restarted the computer.

Funny thing is, when I run the debugger in eclipse,
it does run the application on the phone, it just doesn't recognize it
(and of course debug breakpoints are useless in this mode).

Would appreicate any help- thanks.

Comment: I did, In my case it shows "no AVD available" not an unrecognized device. updating the driver didn't work. thanks anyway :)

Comment: Thanks , I finnaly got this to work. if you wish to convert your comment to an answer I would happily upvote and select it :-)

Comment: Done, posted as a community wiki :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a driver issue. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3470439/1893766). Did not work, install alternative drivers.

You seem to have already tried [Kies](http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/): try installing drivers separately([ref](http://clockworkmod.com/tether/drivers)):

1. Go to the [Samsung Mobile](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones) site
2. Search for your phone using the search
   box.
3. Once you find your phone, click Support in the top right of the
   phone's product page.
4. In the list of downloads, download and install
   the USB Driver.

If that still does not work try [Universal Naked Driver](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1996051) and/or [Universal ADB Driver](https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/BQ5iYJEaaEH).