# Unplugging causes Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, device

Seriously going nuts with this.

**I don't want a solution that tells me to restart eclipse or anything slow like that. Killing adb and restart eclipse is obviously going to work. But am I supposed to waste 1 full min restarting adb just to upload an APK and do some testing?**

What happens is I upload apk in eclipse by clicking debug, then I unplug my device to do testing. Because after unplugging, the device run much faster than plugged.

**Every single time I unplug my device, I run into this problem on Windows. Doesn't happen on my Eclipse on Mac.**

Comment: use android studio instead of eclipse

Comment: Could be driver issue, try to update Android USB driver or install [alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17027966/1893766).

Answer (score 0):

Solution1
**run this command: adb uninstall com.yourpackagename**

Solution2
This is not an answer to solve problem with unplugging.

However, if you set android:debuggable="false" in your manifest, then running your android in release mode with the wire plugged in is quite fast.

So if you don't switch devices, u don't need to unplug your device then.

it is 10x speed up vs running in debug mode.

Comment: Are you sure this is a difference in the manifest setting, and not simply the difference between using the "run" button and using the "debug" one?  I've never noticed a particular speed difference with the ADB cable connected, but then I almost never connect the debugger (since most problems have solutions which are obvious from the logs)

Comment: I think if you run in release mode whatever way, it will be fast. My release button didn't work, that's why I set it in manifest.

Comment: No, not release.  Simply the difference between starting an APK normally (ie, "running" - comparable to starting it from the launcher on device, or any other source of a normal Intent), vs starting it with the debugger (well, the wait for debugger to connect flag)  There's a world of difference between a apk which would accept a debugger connection but is running without, and one which actually has the debugger presently connected, or is intentionally hung waiting for that connection.

Comment: Why do you think you should uninstall the package??  That shouldn't be needed.