# adb does not recognize Android 4.0.4 device

Tags: android, adb

I have two Android phones

1. *Alcatel One Touch 4030D*, Android version 4.1.1, kernel version 3.4.0
2. *Highscreen Spark*, Android version 4.0.4, kernel version 3.0.21-perf.

`adb devices` detects the Alcatel phone, but not the Highscreen phone.

I tried to run `adb kill-server; adb start-server`, but it didn't help. Switching between different connection modes (*Media device (MTP)*, *USB storage*) didn't help either. USB debugging is enabled.

Here are the screenshots of the *Developer options* settings:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

How can I make adb recognize the Highscreen device?

**Update 1 (03.08.2013 19:00 MSK):** Adding the line `0454` to `adb_usb.ini` didn't help.

**Update 2 (03.08.2013 19:59 MSK):** My attempt to follow the official [Google recommendations](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) failed because I couldn't find the drivers for the Highscreen Spark device.

Comment: There are some "naked" driver. Have your tried one of these?

Comment: @B770 No. Where can I download them?

Comment: Check xda devs. I dont know if it works for your defice.

Comment: did you install Google USB Drivers from Android Developer Tools?

Comment: Have you tried to run adb server as root ? sudo ./adb start-server

Comment: @buzeeg I'm working on Windows 7. I don't think this is user permission issue because adb works fine a) with AndroVM emulator and b) the Alcatel phone.

Comment: @triclosan I installed the "Android developer tools" package (including eclipse). I don't know whether the Google USB driver is installed. How can I find this out?

Comment: check Android SDK Manager http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html

Comment: you referred Google recommendations about OEM drivers AFAIK its for lowlevel USB access bootflashing, etc...

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17027966/1893766) helps.

Comment: @shoerat Installing Universal ADB driver didn't help.

Comment: Try uninstalling every existing ADB drivers (for all Android phones/tablets that you have installed before) and then try with Universal Naked Driver and/or Universal ADB Driver.

Comment: I'm not sure which version of Jelly Bean introduces that feature, but there is a security "opt-in" on your phone that pops up a message on USB debugging attempt from an unknown development PC. You need to grant access on your phone. If you set up your phone with multiple users then this opt-in popup can remain hidden if you switched to a secondary user account. Only the primary user account can see that popup.

Comment: You can find the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7136003/1773317

Answer (score 3):

If you could setup an ADT on Linux or Mac, it will work out of the box.
We were able to connect all sorts of devices to adb easily with ADT on Linux/Mac.

Comment: Could you please explain why Linux/Mac version of adb can work with devices in absence of their drivers and Windows can't?

Comment: More information can be found here: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: Android uses the Linux Kernel, any OS that uses the Linux Kernel is basically still a Linux so the drivers aren't needed anymore because Linux already have the libraries that Android needs. Windows is a different system and that is why you still need the driver files to make it work

Comment: this is NOT an answer.  this is a comment.  please edit including SPECIFIC info.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't managed to connect it through usb, you can try the network connection.
Add your device to the same network, then type in the command prompt:

```
adb connect your_device_ip_address
```

Comment: I thought about that (I use this command in order to connect to AndroVM emulator). How can I find out the IP address of the phone?

Comment: I can see the IP address following "Settings -> About Device -> Status -> IP address". Hope can help you

Comment: Just tried it out - I'm getting the error message `unable to connect to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5555`. USB debugging is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Hey try to dig for drivers at [Official website](http://support.highscreen.org).

May be search other sites for USB drivers, that may help you to come out of your problem.

Comment: If you enter "Spark" in their search form, you find zero results.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem .Try it again by activating the usb mass storage.

Comment: I did this already (tried out all available connection options).

Answer (score 1):

Without `adb driver` for device (in your case Highscreen Spark) it is almost impossible to create a bridge(connection) between your program and device, as `adb` (Android Debug bridge) makes a connection between your PC/laptop to your android device And without `Adb` in `windows` Pc/Laptops its not easily possible to debug.

Because of this, Companies like samsung, lg, htc are providing adb drivers to users for easy debugging, if you dont have a `adb` driver for Your Device you have only one choice left , Change your operating System into `linux` and then see the magic.

Comment: Ad changing to Linux: Why is the Linux version of adb able to work without device drivers and the Windows version isn't?

Comment: First of all i would like to tell you i am rookie, and for your question i think that android is a linux based operating system and that why we dont need to create a bridge between devices , but in some devices we do need to install adb, But in windows we need to create a bridge and for that we need drivers for it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.  Turns out, the issue was the USB Port I plugged in to.  The port directly on my laptop does **not** allow for ADB to see the device.  The port on the back of my docking station **does** allow ADB to see the device.  I believe it has to do with USB 3.0 vs. 2.0.  I believe 3.0 blocks the protocol ADB needs to use.

Answer (score 0):

You will actually require the device drivers to connect it, so try insatalling `Highscreen Spark`'s PC Suite.

If that dosen't work or you don't find the PC Suite you can download  [Moborobo from here](http://www.moborobo.com/)  which is a universal PC Suite for smart phones and connect the device with it and then try connecting the device from `abd`

Comment: Can you please provide the URL for downloading the "Highscreen Spark PC Suite"?

Comment: sorry buddy, I tried finding the pc suite for Highscreen Spark but wasn't able to find it, so I mentioned Moborobo, try using it instead , it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem with your adb.exe. I had the same problem earlier for connecting **HCL G1 tablet**. I also added lines in android_winusb.ini, but could not connect yet. 
Then I found out this link. I got solution by changing the adb.exe file. Try this link : 
http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/37692-adb-drivers-problem/ Or 
 just download the adb.exe from following link and replace it with you adb.exe file.
 http://sdrv.ms/NepKED 
It is also suggested run this command to make adb_usb.ini effective for respective adb after modifying. 
 **echo 0x2207 >> %USERPROFILE%.android\adb_usb.ini**

Answer (score 0):

Try these drivers 
[x86](https://disk.yandex.ru/public/?hash=cGOas67LU%2brnneuO6tTHuYNqsN2PeINiUCA3o48NwpY=) 
[x64](https://disk.yandex.ru/public/?hash=dHqPu30kdxTvJp0xgMWBeydQMJVf64wEt6zXxF/Hgnw=) 
It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

After head banging for more than a day - a small thing saved my life on my RK3066 based device:

after you update the adb_usb.ini and everything else,
and after you do a

```
adb kill-server
```

do a

```
adb usb
```

and **only then** do a

```
adb devices
```

saved my life

By the way

> Adding the line 0454 to adb_usb.ini didn't help.

you should be adding **0x454**

Comment: My device is a rk30sdk based rk3066 android usb tv dongle.

Comment: Another thing you need to try:

If your computer doesnt recognize the USB, try turning on the bluetooth interface in the control panel. In my case it allowed the computer to detect the box.

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with my android phone showing up when I typed adb devices but found out that it was the usb cable which caused the issue, members in my family have two different android phones each with their own charging cable. I was using one phone with the other phones usb cable just because it was the nearest and I didn't think it would make a difference but it did.

Try a different usb cable and that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in the past but i don't found the driver on my computer today, so :

You can go on http://www.alcatelonetouch.com and find the call center for your land. 
Call them , and explain the issue , they have to send you a driver to connect your phone to the computer. This drivers is very easy to install.
I have make that and i can use it for debbuging

I whish you good luck... Sorry for my English