# Eclipse/Android Studio Device not showing up in Chooser Dialog

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am trying to debug my android application on a device but it is not showing me any device connected in the chooser dialog. What could be the problem ?

I've tried to change connect and disconnect the device again.
I restarted the eclipse
I checked **Window->Preferences->Android** it shows me the SDK Targets.

What else can I do. My Computer recognizes the device but the eclipse chooser dialog doesn't show any device connected.

Please help...

Comment: Is debug enabled on your device? Starting from jelly bean you need to enable it to debug..

Comment: are you talking about usb debugging in mobile ? I've enabled it.

Comment: try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721778/adb-no-devices-found

Comment: I tried to restart the adb server but still  no success. When I try to connect my device to my laptop it does not install one of the drivers and shows my device on my laptop but not the IDE chooser dialog.I think that can be a reason but don't know what to do

Comment: Do you run Windows 8? And if you run 'adb devices' in your terminal, does it show your device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a third party software named "moborobo" : http://www.moborobo.com/

You can install this there after you didn't need any driver for any perticular mobile device...it will automatically gets detected and you can choose it from the dialogue box. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your device connected as PTP device(Camera). Notification Bar -> USB Connection.
If your device connected as MTP(as common data storage) then AndroidStudio don't recognize it as debuggable device. At least that works for me and my Nexus.

Answer (score 0):

There is another method that you can use .....when you run your project as android project, it generates an .apk file. Just move that .apk file to your device. Then on device run the application in debug mode.

Comment: can you please find out any solution for this problem so that i can debug it using eclipse ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429959/why-is-eclipses-android-device-chooser-not-showing-my-android-device?rq=1                Please refer to the above mentioned link....Hope this will solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is: killing adb.exe (using Windows Task Manager) (your IDE will restart it when needed automatically)

If you have more than one IDE open (for instance eclipse and Android-Studio): shutdown one of them, because there may have some conflicts between them when trying to connect with ADB.

If your device was never recognized through ADB (never shows up in eclipse chooser dialog, nor in Android-Studio chooser dialog): then you can try to install the generic Android Driver provided by Google (`<SDK_HOME>/extras/google/usb_driver/`)

Answer (score 0):

I often encounter this problem, particularly when starting a particular emulator device for the first time that day. i.e. I launch my app, choose the device, the device starts up - but not before the launch of my app has timed out. I find that although the emulator device appears to have started properly - Eclipse does not recognise it as a "running Android device".

I simply shut down the device and repeat the process. I find that the second attempt is (almost) always successful - even if the app launch "times out", the emulator will be talking to Eclipse and I can then relaunch my app on the running emulator device.

Increasing the ADB connection timeout (defaults to 5000ms: Window...Preferences...Android...DDMS) may or may not help.

Hope this helps !

Comment: @IanB you can simply reset adb from eclipse's emulator control. It's faster than rebooting emulator!