# Why won't my Droid Mini show up in devices for Eclipse? [Windows]

Tags: java, android, windows, eclipse

I've seen this question asked a couple of times, but none of them have a working answer for my situation. I have Windows, I'm using Eclipse, using a Droid Mini which I have plugged into my laptop (of course), and I have USB Debugging on my phone on.
Another post I saw:
[Why is Eclipse's Android Device Chooser not showing my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429959/why-is-eclipses-android-device-chooser-not-showing-my-android-device)
showed an unknown device, but mine doesn't show any device at all. I updated APIs 16-18, all of the tools, the Android Support Library, and the Google USB Driver. I went into Manage>Device Manager, and according to http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Win7 I should look in Other Devices to find my phone to install the driver, and then it should show up under "Android Phones" later for me to update the driver. Mine was enver under "Other Devices", it was under "Portable Devices", and it still is. The "Android Phones" section never showed up.

Comment: Have you installed the [Motorola Device Manager](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I missed that lol The answer is Geobits' comment above. THANKS! Just too many things to install, and I'm pretty sure it failed to install something the first time, and it worked the second time... Anyways, thanks I can now use my apps on my phone instead of the laggy emulators :)