# Viewsonic VSD 220 not listing on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android-hardware

I bought a Viewsonic VSD 220 (android) display to test my application,Problem is when i connect to my laptop eclipse not listing this device under the device section. i couldn't find the drivers for this even in the viewsonic site, if some one can help me to find this driver or any other way to debug the application through the eclipse  please let me know.

Comment: You might want to try some solutions from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429959/why-is-eclipses-android-device-chooser-not-showing-my-android-device For me it once helped to use another USB-port to recognize my device.

Comment: i'm struggle to find the driver for this device?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, but I was able to solve it using the Universal ADB driver*.  The driver can be found at: https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver

***NOTE**: I had to android_winusb.inf to include the ViewSonic device info:

```
;ViewSonic
%ViewSonic%             = USB_Install, USB\VID_0408&PID_3998&REV_0216&MI_01
%ViewSonic%             = USB_Install, USB\VID_0408&PID_3998&MI_01
```

The updates have been merged into the main branch already and should have to is clone the repo and install the driver manually from usb_driver.