# unable to find my real android device in android device chooser

Tags: android, plugins, genymotion

After installation of Genymotion plugin to eclipse am unable to find my real android device connected through USB cable. It is showing only the geny motion virtual device.

Please guide me in this issue.

Comment: you have to install the  device USB driver.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429959/why-is-eclipses-android-device-chooser-not-showing-my-android-device see this

Comment: @Yugesh it was worked previously well. Just testing purpose i install this to eclipse yesterday. Today am unable to find my device in device chooser. I tried adb kill-server and adb start-server also..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429959/why-is-eclipses-android-device-chooser-not-showing-my-android-device

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay its connected to my system. Also installed all the driver software for my device.

Comment: ok than please do one thing uninstall the installed previous driver and , again do the same process, hope it will help you

Comment: @user2865487 connect the USB and restart the adb in eclipse.

Comment: @Yugesh i done that also.. no use...

Comment: @Yugesh just now i tried that again after uninstall. it works well.. thanks.

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay thanks for your suggestion. i solved by uninstalling and reconnect my device again. Also i used adb-killserver and adb-start server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall (and reinstall) the device under Window's "Device List".

Comment: Press START -> write "devices" open devices list, choose ADB interface uninstall it and then reconnect your device.

Comment: Try START -> COMPUTER (properties) -> DEVICE LIST