# Eclipse ADT shows my phone as ??????????, won't install APK

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, motorola-droid

I just purchased a Motorola Droid 4 to replace my old Samsung. When testing builds on the Samsung it always showed up in Eclipse's "Android Device Chooser" window, but the Droid shows up as "?????????" and the "Ok" button is disabled so I can't proceed with the installation and launch.

I've followed the directions on this page:

https://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up

And have found the same results.

I also checked the output for "adb devices" after setting up the UDEV rule, restarting UDEV, and unplugging/re-plugging the phone, and it still showed:

```
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

However, as per Marecky's suggestion on this page:

[Why is Eclipse's Android Device Chooser not showing my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429959/why-is-eclipses-android-device-chooser-not-showing-my-android-device)

...if I kill the adb server and then try "sudo adb devices" it seems to list my phone properly!

```
List of devices attached 
015ECD710F00A017    device
```

So my question is, why is Eclipse's Android Device Chooser window still displaying the phone as "????????" when adb is showing the device properly on the command line?

Do I need to tell Eclipse to run its ADB plugin as root too? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Unplug the device, unlock the screen, plug it back in and confirm android debugging permission.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. Apparently with the Motorola Droid 4, when the USB Mass Storage option is set (whether or not it's enabled) the Debugging mode doesn't work.

I changed the "USB computer connection" settings from "Mass Storage" to "Camera (PTP)" and now the "USB debugging" works!